# centos 8 can not list or /dev MacBook Pro 2020 internal hard disk

Tags: macos

i just received a new MacBook Pro 2020 and i'm trying to completely wipe the internal hard disk to start with a fresh drive with no partitions. i can boot to CentOS 8 linux from a thumb drive. when i do:

```
lsblk
ls /dev/sd*
ls /dev/nvme*
```

from the shell or terminal, i can not find any trace of the internal hard disk of the mac itself.

how come? and how do i access it so i can:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvm_whatever_drive bs=10M
```

am i making sense? thank you in advance, lucas

Comment: What about `sudo lshw -class disk`?

Comment: ok, i tried "lshw -class disk" and "lshw" is not on the centos 8 bootable disk.  i "find / -name lshw" and its not to be found.  if "find / -name lsblk" it is found under /usr/bin.  i state the latter just to make sure find is working ok.  so, Apple must be designing hardware that is so proprietary that linux can not detect or access it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always boot a Mac installer thumb drive, which will work out of the box and will detect the hard disk regardless. While in the installer, you can open a terminal and execute dd if you want to.

Comment: yes, i know i could do that and i have.  its the only way to access the hard disk.  the point of using linux is to wipe a drive so clean as to override whatever measures Apple puts into Disk Utility to protect "their" proprietary hardware.  so, Apple must be designing hardware that is so proprietary that linux can not detect or access it.